# NTFS Permissions - SYSTEM

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, acl

Are there any possible side effects to removing permissions for `SYSTEM` on an NTFS directory? It is a non-system (user documents) folder. I know the obvious (i.e., that `SYSTEM` will no longer to be able to access it, duh :-) ).

My question is, **are there any common side-effects this can have?** I.e., common reasons on an average Windows system, that would require the `SYSTEM` account to have access? *I'm thinking of things like Indexing Service here (although I don't use or care about that particular service).*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most Windows services are running under the SYSTEM account. [Windows Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Search) Indexer, for example, runs under Local System account. If LocalSystem account cannot access your files, they will not be indexed / found via Windows Search.

There could be other side-effects, mostly related to the fact that many services (including third-party ones) are built with the assumption that user files are accessible to the system account.

So, in theory you can remove these permissions, but in practice you need a really good reason to do so.

Comment: FYI: Norton Internet Security uses the `SYSTEM` account as well.  If you use NIS, it will not be able to scan any files in folders which the Local System account cannot access.

Comment: general installation?  depending on the OS.  I am thinking nothing good could come of it, but it would be fun to try :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the directory gives access to Administrators, then it is not necessary to give access to SYSTEM.  Any access token including SYSTEM will also have Administrators.