# Is "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" a user or a group?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, local-groups

In Windows the user `System` is displayed with the group symbol:
[image].
*(Using the internal Win32 API [LookupAccountSid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa379166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also reveals that it seems to be a group [SidTypeGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa379601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).)*

On the other hand processes can run in the `system context` like in a `user context`. Also Microsoft documents describe it as "system user" or "system account", and not as "system group".

**Is it a user which is for any legacy purposes displayed as group?**

(Or is it something [Werner Heisenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) would have been interested in?)

---

*Note: [What is the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user?](https://superuser.com/questions/471769/what-is-the-nt-authority-system-user/471774) is similar but doesn't answer the question why it is displayed as group and behaves like an user.*

Comment: This maybe answer your? question here: http://superuser.com/questions/471769/what-is-the-nt-authority-system-user/471774

Comment: You are right my bad apologize

Comment: SIDs don't have to be either of those, do they?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First, [access token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa374909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
contains much more than the [security identifier (SID)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa379571(v=vs.85).aspx). One only has to "Run as administrator"
a program to see in the Task Manager that its user is oneself and not
Administrator, and this miracle is achieved just by the modification of the
access token, not by replacing the SID.

Second, NT-AUTHORITY and SYSTEM are neither accounts nor groups,
in spite of what say various other sources (even inside Microsoft).
An SID usually has a name that is displayed whenever required.
A user account will contribute its SID as principal SID to the access token,
which will also determine the name displayed by various utilities.
But the access token may contain additional SIDs, for example for all the groups
to which belongs that user account. When checking permissions, Windows will
look for any SID in the access token that has that permission.

Some well-known Windows SIDs will have names reported by Windows,
although they do not really belong to any account.

A [Security Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier)
is defined by Wikipedia as :

> a unique, immutable identifier of a user, user group, or
>   **other security principal**.

The SID does not need to even define a user account or a group.
It just defines a set of permissions. The above Wikipedia article adds:

> Windows grants or denies access and privileges to resources based on
>   access control lists (ACLs), which use SIDs to uniquely identify users
>   and their group memberships. When a user logs into a computer, an
>   access token is generated that contains user and group SIDs and user
>   privilege level. When a user requests access to a resource, the access
>   token is checked against the ACL to permit or deny particular action
>   on a particular object.

The SID of `NT-AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` can be added to other accounts.
For example, this is said about the
[LocalSystem Account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The LocalSystem account is a predefined local account used by the
>   service control manager. [...] **Its token includes
>   the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM and BUILTIN\Administrators SIDs;
>   these accounts** have access to most system objects.

One can already see in the above text the confusion that reigns even in
Microsoft documentation as regarding system SIDs, which are not exactly accounts nor groups - which are just a set of permissions.
This confusion further extends to other utilities and articles, so any
returned information should be carefully examined.

The Microsoft article
[Well-known security identifiers in Windows operating systems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems)
details all system SIDs, some of whom I include below:

[image]

**Conclusion**: NT-AUTHORITY\SYSTEM is the name of a Security ID,
which is neither a group nor an account.
It is displayed in Task Manager as SYSTEM when it is the principal SID of a
program. The most I would call it is "a pseudo account".

Comment: You beat me to it my friend. I was halfway through writing a similar answer when your answer came in. This is the proper explanation. It is just a collection of permissions and whether it is displayed as a group or a user is both wrong. As most tools can only show either "user or "group" they just pick one or the other. Usually group as the WIn32 API sets  SidTypeGroup accordingly and that is were most applications get their info from.

Comment: Wow! I start a bounty to reward an existing answer, and what happens? A better answer appears. :-) One question though: Does the LocalSystem account also have its own ("account") SID or does it simply use the NT-AUTHORTY\SYSTEM SID as its principal SID?

Comment: @Heinzi: LocalSystem is another "pseudo account". One can see this in the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx) which says : "This account is not recognized by the security subsystem, so you cannot specify its name in a call to the LookupAccountName function".

Comment: `- which are just a set of permissions`: does the *which* refer to the *System IDs* or to the *accounts or groups*?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: Both.

Comment: Why the processes that run under NT-AUUTHORITY/SYSTEM user have different access rights and many cannot even access what is permitted to "SYSTEM"?

Answer (score 9):

IMHO your observation is correct. `NT-AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` is a group, so you could refer to it as the system *group*. This group [exists since Windows NT 4](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windowsnt/4/server/proddocs/en-us/concept/xcp02.mspx?mfr=true) at least and has already been a group there:

> Special Groups
>
> [...]
>
> System - The operating system.

There is also an account called [LocalSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which

> [...] includes the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM [...]

so you could call this the system *user* who is member of the SYSTEM group.

SysInternals [PsGetSid](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb897417.aspx) supports the group theory for SYSTEM:

```
C:\>PsGetsid.exe S-1-5-18

PsGetSid v1.44 - Translates SIDs to names and vice versa
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Account for YOURPCNAMEHERE\S-1-5-18:
Well Known Group: NT-AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
```

Regarding the start of a process as a group:

To manage the security, a process gets an [access token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa374909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The access token contains SIDs only. I'm not sure if there's a check whether the user's SID is really a user or a group. In principle it wouldn't matter: the SID defines what can be accessed. Perhaps the [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/133375/Starting-Process-in-the-Logged-Session-under-the-L) can help with the implementation