# So when we open a file with "Run as adminstrator" which user we are using?

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions, notepad

So when we click the "Run as administrator" in any program it doesn't ask for a password? so what user is performing operations there?

Here is what I'm trying to do - I'm trying to edit `/etc/hosts` and currently I'm logged in as a administrator, I tried this in terminal

```
runas /user:MACHINE_NAME\username notepad <path_to_etc_hosts>
```

It opens, shows me the content of `drivers/etc/hosts` files but when I try to save it I get an alert saying that I dont have permission to save this file ?

Now when I `DIR /q` inside `/divers/etc/hosts` I find that its owned by `AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` not by the user `my_logged_in_user`

so now I have two questions, the might sound very silly (sorry) -

1. How do I edit the file
2. How "run as an administrator" (GUI actually works? which user is being used to open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` is a reserved pseudo account that is used by Windows.
Administrator permissions are not enough to edit such a file.

You should use the
[psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)
utility by Mark Russinovich, to execute commands under the SYSTEM account.
Be very careful in this mode to only update the file and get out of it
when finished.

Run a Command Prompt (cmd) as Administrator and enter the following command:

```
psexec -i -d -s C:\Windows\notepad.exe C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

The argument `-s` means "Run the remote process in the System account".

For more information see my answer in the post
[Is "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" a user or a group?](https://superuser.com/questions/1067246/is-nt-authority-system-a-user-or-a-group/1216142#1216142)